# Графы. Поиск ключей от комнат. Python

Tags: python, алгоритм, графы

Помогите решить задачу. Скорее всего неверный алгоритм. Я решаю ее на `stepik` и там не показывает какой тест не проходит, отчего не пойму где ошибка. И решение не засчитывает. Я попробовал решить без переменной `v`, т.к. не понятно как ее использовать.

**Задача:**

Представьте, что вы попали в большой замок, в котором `N` комнат (под номерами `0..N-1`), а вы находитесь в комнате под номером `0`. В каждой комнате спрятаны ключи, которые позволяют попасть в другую комнату.

В каждой комнате `i` есть список чисел `rooms[i]`, обозначающий список ключей, который хранится в этой комнате. Каждый ключ `j` открывает некоторую комнату под номером `v: rooms[i][j] = v`

В начале все комнаты закрыты.
Верните `True`, если все комнаты в замке могут быть открыты, а иначе верните `False`.

**Вот мой код:**

```
class Solution:        
def canVisitAllRooms(self, rooms: list):
    verifyList=[]
    tst = [i for i in range(len(rooms))]
    for i in range(len(rooms)):
        tf=0
        if len(rooms[i])>0:
            for j in rooms[i]:
                if i != j and j in range(len(rooms)): tf += 1
                print('ключ из комнаты', i, 'открывает комнату', j)
            print('совпадений - ', tf)
            verifyList.append(tf)

    if 0 in verifyList: return False
    else: return True
```

Comment: Решил задачу :)

Comment: Опубликуйте свое решение как ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаю итеративное решение.

Оно имеет следующие преимущества:

- Максимальная, дефолтная глубина рекурсии в Python 1000 вызовов, соответственно рекурсивное решение не сможет обработать больше 1000 комнат.
- Для хранения посещённых комнат используется структура данных `set`, что позволяет проверять посещена ли комната за константное время - **O(1)**.

**Алгоритм:**

1. Создаём набор (`set`) ключей, помещаем в него ключ от комнаты № **0**.
2. Достаём ключ из набора, если он от непосещённой комнаты, заходим в неё.
3. Добавляем все ключи из новой комнаты в набор ключей.
4. Добавляем комнату в посещённые.
5. Если в наборе остались ключи, возращаемся в пункт 2.
6. Возращаем результат сравнения количества посещённых комнат с общим количеством.

```
class Solution:
    def canVisitAllRooms(self, rooms):
        key_set = {0} 
        visited = set()

        while key_set:
            key = key_set.pop()

            if key not in visited:
                key_set.update(rooms[key])
                visited.add(key)

        return len(visited) == len(rooms)
```

Answer (score 3):

**Решил в итоге задачу, за неимением ответов на вопрос) получилось вот так:**

```
def canVisitAllRooms(self, rooms: list):
    # создаем закрытые комнаты
    visited = [False] * (len(rooms))

    def dfs(s, visited):
        #если комната открыта, то true
        if visited[s]:
            return True
        # иначе открываем текущую комнату
        visited[s] = True
        # и проверяем ключи из этой комнаты
        for neighbor in rooms[s]:
            #print(neighbor)
            dfs(neighbor, visited)


    s=0
    #print(dfs(0, visited))
    dfs(0, visited)

    # проверка открытых комнат
    if False in visited: return False
    else: return True
```